# jssor sliders swipe in the same time

Tags: slider, jssor

I have two Jssor "nearby-image-partial-visible-slider" on the same page and I would like them to swipe/move in the same time. Is this possible? Can somebody tell me how can I achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;

//set $AutoPlay: false for the second slider
var options2 = {
    ...,
    $AutoPlay: false,
    ...
}

var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options2);

function OnPositionChange(position) {
    //let jssor_slider2 go to the same position as jssor_slider1
    jssor_slider2.$GoTo(position);
}

//listen $JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE on jssor_slider1
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnPositionChange);
```

**To make slider1 swipe along with slider2**

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;
var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$(...;

function OnPositionChange(position) {
    //let jssor_slider1 go to the same position as jssor_slider2
    jssor_slider1.$GoTo(position);
}

//listen $JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE on jssor_slider2
jssor_slider2.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnPositionChange);
```

**Edit:**

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;
var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$(...;

function OnPositionChange(position) {
    jssor_slider1.$GoTo(position);
    jssor_slider2.$GoTo(position);
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnPositionChange);
jssor_slider2.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnPositionChange);
```

Comment: My sliders have the same options, with '$AutoPlay: false', because I need them to move only when I swipe. So, how can I make jssor_slider1 go to the same position as jssor_slider2 ? I've tried this but it doesn't work:
function OnPositionChange(position) {
    jssor_slider1.$GoTo(position);
    jssor_slider2.$GoTo(position);
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnPositionChange);
jssor_slider2.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnPositionChange);

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I need Slider1 to swipe along with Slider2, and Slider2 to swipe along with Slider1. Thank you!

Comment: It should work. Please set `$AutoPlay: true` for one of the sliders.

Comment: Sorry, this is a bug. I have just got it fixed. Please download the latest version.

Comment: Upload failed, please wait. Or you can download from github. https://github.com/jssor/slider/archive/master.zip